# imagen dentro de collectionViewCell cambia de posición

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Estoy trabajando con `UICollectionView`. Estoy intentando cargar unas imágenes (Ya lo he logrado), y cuando cargo la vista por primera vez todo va perfecto, pero cuando regreso a la vista anterior y vuelvo a entrar al `CollectionView` las imágenes se han reajustado.

Primera carga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segunda Carga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi `CollectionViewCell`:

```
class PhotoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!{
    didSet {

        photo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill//ScaleToFill//ScaleAspectFit//ScaleToFill
        photo.clipsToBounds = true

    }
}

}
```

Y la parte donde cargo mis imágenes:

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    let seccion = items[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.label.text = String(indexPath.row)

    let imageURL = NSURL( string: seccion.value! as! String)
    cell.photo.sd_setImageWithURL(imageURL)
 return cell}
```

Y la ubicación del `UIImageview`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego lo siguiente por si estoy haciendo algo mal en la definición del tamaño de las celdas:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width / 3)-10
    let heigth = width
    return CGSizeMake(width, heigth)
}

// En viewDidLoad.
    collectionView!.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
```

Editado 16-sept-2016

Después de agregar algunas otras imágenes he visto que el cambio de tamaño del `UIImageView` es "temporal", se reajusta después de dar scroll.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITADO 17-Septiembre-2016**

Bien, después de buscar por aquí y por allá he logrado que funcione, pero sigo sin comprender.

He añadido a mi `CollectionViewCell`:

```
    override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    super.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Y en mi clase `CollectionView` dentro del `collectionView(...cellForItemAtIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

Despues de `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusa....`
he añadido:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
```

Esta línea es indiferente, funciona igual esté o no esté. **¿Por qué?**.

```
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

y la cosa funciona, ahora mis imágenes se cargan correctamente, sin embargo olvidemos que he hecho lo anterior y pasemos a la parte donde descargo mis datos y agreguemos:

```
self.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Después de:

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

Y también funciona. ¿Por qué funciona? y ¿cuál de ambas soluciones es la mejor?

Comment: Buff realmente veo demasiada complicación para lo que querías hacer , pero si ya lo tienes resuelto mejor , el layoutIfNeeded lo que hace es preparar el layout para el cambio , por alguna razon no te cojé bien las constraints o el aspectMode de inicio y luego cuando hacias scroll si , al añadir esto la subvista ya se prepara de inicio , por ese motivo te funciona.

Answer (score 0):

El tamaño de la celda es descartable por que la celda sigue teniendo el mismo tamaño , yo creo que el problema esta en el aspecto de la imagen , como prueba podrias trasladar lo que haces en el didSet a la configuración de la celda o directamente al guión gráfico.
Es bastante posible que al entrar por segunda vez no este entrando bien en el didSet y no te este cogiendo bien el contentMode de la imagen

Comment: Inicialmente lo que tengo el el didSet lo tenia en la configuración de la celda. y ya he probado con los distintos tipos de ViewContentMode y en todos la tendencia es que recorre la imagen hacia la parte inferior y al lado derecho. Estoy empezando a pensar que debe ser alguna especie de vudu o tener un origen ajeno a esta realidad.